# Como melhor o text-to-speech no meu app android, não está respeitando os sinais de pontuação?

Tags: java, android

app já fala o que escrevo, mas se eu escrever um pergunta com sinal de pontuação (?) não pronuncia como uma pergunta, a pronuncia é muito rápida, como faço para melhorar?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
private TextToSpeech TTS;
private Button BTN;
private EditText EDT;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TTS = new TextToSpeech(this,this);
    BTN = findViewById(R.id.btn_ouvir_texto);
    EDT = findViewById(R.id.edt_input_txt);

    BTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SpeechOut();
        }

    });
}

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
    if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
    {
        int result = TTS.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
        if(result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED || result ==TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA)
        {
            Log.e("TTS", "Idioma não suportado");
        }else{
            BTN.setEnabled(true);
            SpeechOut();
        }
    }else {
        Log.e("TTS","Inicialização falhou...");
    }
}
    private void SpeechOut()
    {
        String text = EDT.getText().toString();
        TTS.speak(text,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

A implementação do mecanismo de TTS é responsabilidade de seu provedor (sistema ou aplicativo da loja) e pode ou não suportar personalização dos parâmetros de leitura, logo o resultado da leitura pode divergir consideravelmente entre dispositivos.

Ajustar a entonação da voz de acordo com a pontuação é uma tarefa que exige uma ferramenta TTS robusta. De acordo com algumas fontes, a versão embarcada do Android suporta um subconjunto do [SSML](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml) (linguagem de marcação para síntese de voz), que pode melhorar alguns aspectos da leitura, como as pausas entre palavras. Você deve considerar também a utilização de uma ferramenta online, como o [Google Cloud Text to Speech](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/), que tem um suporte mais abrangente do SSML.

Sugiro a leitura [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573030/using-tts-on-android-punctuation-is-read-aloud) (em inglês) no SO.